# Rent a car without credit card in Portugal

Tags: car-rentals, portugal, porto

We will go to Porto tomorrow and ordered a credit card but it is delayed. So we are in trouble renting a car in Porto. Any idea if it is possible to rent a car without a credit card there and if so where?

Answer (score 2):

I just called a few car rentals in Porto and Sixt allows cash but you have to bring a printout from your bank with the driver's information, Swift code and stuff. The money will be transferred back to your bank account in about one week after you bring back the car.

Answer (score 0):

In the smaller car group categories [Imperial Car Rental](https://www.imperial-car-rental.com/en-Car-Rental/) does not ask for you CC information assuming you purchase the FDW insurance. This is how it works in Croatia, Greece & Spain, I assume that this is their policy in Portugal as well.